# Why shift by a constant doesn't affect integral for $f \in L^2[0,2\pi]$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

For $f \in L^2[0,2\pi]$, a solution to a problem I've been trying to solve states the following:

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x-t)|^2dt=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2dt$$

Why is that? There is nothing else stated about $f$ (I would expect it to be periodic for this to hold, but it's not). Is there some consensus I can't remember where we just assume it becomes periodic outside the domain?

In any case, would appreciate knowing how to show this is true formally.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since $x-t$ otherwise would not always be an element in $[0,2\pi]$. Namely for example $x>0$ and $t=0$ you would have $-t\not\in [0,2\pi]$. Thus $f$ is indeed $2\pi$ periodic on $\mathbb{R}$. Can you then show it is true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)$ is a periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $T=2\pi$. We have $f(x)=f(x+2n\pi)$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Define: $u=x-t$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x-t)|^2dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x-2\pi}^x|f(u)|^2du=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{x+2\pi}_x|f(u)|^2du$$

If $x=2n\pi$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{x+2\pi}_x|f(u)|^2du=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0|f(u)|^2du$$

If $x\neq2n\pi$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then let $x=2n\pi+y$, where $y\in (0,2\pi)$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{x+2\pi}_x|f(u)|^2du&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{y+2\pi}_y|f(u)|^2du\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0|f(u)|^2du+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{y+2\pi}_{2\pi}|f(u)|^2du-\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{y}|f(u)|^2du\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0|f(u)|^2du+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{y}_{0}|f(u)|^2du-\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{y}|f(u)|^2du\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0|f(u)|^2du\end{align}$$